# How to get back stashed changes without solving git pull merge conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

I have three branches, branch `a`,`b` and branch `HotFix`.

I was working on branch HotFix, where I was solving an issue, then I got a call for another work. I need to switch to branch `b`. I stashed my current branch changes and then I do `git checkout b` after that `git pull origin b`.

After pulling the changes git bash shows me merge conflicts, these are really huge number of files, I don't want to resolve the conflicts manually. I have lost my local branch `HotFix` and its work. Is there any way to get back the stashed changes without resolving conflicts.

---

What I think I am looking for a `git unpull` or `git reverse pull`.

Comment: This, by the way, is one of the strongest reasons I have to suggest that new Git users *avoid* `git pull`: it's really two separate commands, and if you had run the two separate commands, you would be that much closer to knowing how to *undo* the second command (where it all went wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you ran was `git pull origin b` : it is the combination of two commands :

- first `git fetch origin b` update a local branch named `origin/b`,
- then `git merge origin/b` tries to merge the changes fetched in the first step into the local branch `b`.

Conflicts occur during the second step : the merge. While their are conflicts, the merge is not done so you can cancel with the command `git merge --abort`.

If for some reason the merge is over, you can still undo it, by going back one step in the history with the command `git reset --hard HEAD^`.

In short when you are on branch `b`: `git merge --abort` should work, and if it doesn't, `git reset --hard HEAD^` will.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @DogEata, you saved my life :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform two operations.

1. **Abort the merge**

   You can do this with

   - `git merge --abort`; or
   - `git reset HEAD --hard` (this should not be necessary
2. **Get your stashed work**

   1. Checkout `HotFix` with `git checkout hotfix`; and then
   2. Apply the stash with `git stash apply`.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! @tymtam

Comment: @tymtam Hats off for straight forward answer.